# About has_many and belongs to in cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is my doubt in cakephp 3.0 with has_many and belongs_to:
I need to save two models in one form. This is my models:

CiudananosTable.php:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('ciudadanos');
    $this->displayField('nombrecompleto');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->hasMany('Telefonos', [
        'foreignKey' => 'ciudadano_id'
    ]);
}
```

and TelefonosTable.php:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('telefonos');
    $this->displayField('telefono');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->belongsTo('Ciudadanos', [
        'foreignKey' => 'ciudadano_id'
    ]);
}
```

In my controller:

```
public function add()
{


    $ciudadano = $this->Ciudadanos->newEntity($this->request->data, [
      'associated' => ['Telefonos']]);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $ciudadano = $this->Ciudadanos->patchEntity($ciudadano, $this->request->data, [
          'associated' => ['Telefonos']]);
        if ($this->Ciudadanos->save($ciudadano)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The ciudadano has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The ciudadano could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('ciudadano'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['ciudadano']);
}
```

and this is my form in templates/Ciudadanos/add.ctp

```
<?= $this->Form->create($ciudadano); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Ciudadano') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('nombrecompleto');

        echo $this->Form->input('Telefono.telefono');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

The problem is that in "input('Telefono.telefono');" dont save nothing.
What im doing wrong?

Thanks and sorry my english :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the CakePHP <= 2.x styled naming conventions for your inputs (however it would be wrong for 2.x too), that's not how it works with CakePHP 3.x anymore.

Please refer to the documentation:

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data**

You have to use the appropriate property name of the association as it appears in the entity, which for hasMany associations, is by default the plural, underscored variant of the association alias, so in your case `telefonos`.

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations**

And since hasMany associations need to be passed as nested structures, you need to supply an index, as in `telefonos.0.telefono`.

See also

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions**

**Edit** also note that you shouldn't pass empty arrays into the `newEntity()`, instead pass the request data only to `patchEntity()` on an actual POST request.

Comment: Thank you ndm but is not working :-( I add   echo $this->Form->input('telefonos.0.id');
            echo $this->Form->input('telefonos.0.telefono');

Comment: @JoseRafaelCamejo Sorry, but I can't help you with "_doesn't work_", as this doesn't provide any information that would make it possible for anyone to troubleshoot it.

Comment: @JoseRafaelCamejo At least some debugging results, like what does the passed request data look like, what does the entity look like after patching, are there any validation errors, etc. Also check the edit (even though it's probably not related).